# .innerhtml always fails on first click but works on next click

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript that runs when a button is clicked, it generates a new window for printing.

This script is supposed to add a picture to my document however for some reason it fails to do so on the first click. On IE and Chrome If i close the window and open it again the picture will appear.

On FF the window seems to be stuck in eternal loading.

```
var PrintingWindow = window.open("","View Proof of Pricing",
"toolbar,width=800,height=600,scrollbars,resizable,menubar");
PrintingWindow.document.open();
PrintingWindow.document.write(PrintingHTML);
PrintingWindow.document.getElementById('imageDiv').setAttribute("align", "center");

PrintingWindow.document.getElementById('imageDiv').innerHTML = "<a href='#'><img src='someURL' border='1' width='300' height='170'/></a>"
```

Comment: You're opening the window before you're writing to it, that's why you can only see it after the first time.

Comment: A couple other notes, PrintingHTML appears to be undefined, and document.write is kind of an outdated method.

Comment: PrintingHTML is defined and works correctly. I didn't want to add all the lines that define it. What method instead of write should I use? As for the Opening window How should I do this then I tried putting the window open statement at the end and that doesn't work